# change sequence of columns in apex interactive reports

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

have an interactive report in apex application where I have fields like this:

```
SITE - Title - Position
```

I wish to to change sequence of columns to be for example like this:

```
Title - Position - SITE
```

I cannot find any reference to do so and i believe that should be an easy flip, but I am a beginner in APEX so I don't know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either:

- preview the page (login as a developer account). You will be able to re-order your columns. And save you change as the default report.
- Or simply modify your `SELECT` query.

See [Oracle® Database 2 Day + Application Express Developer's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E14373_01/appdev.32/e13367/build_app.htm#BCEBJJGB) for details.

Comment: I modified the Select eventually, and it worked. But I wish from you to show me how could I re order the columns I logged in as an admin and I cannot re order the sheet.

Comment: Funny how the Layout Sequence has no impact in the developer tool. For the interactive grid, I was able to move mine too; go to the interactive grid as a "user", action, column, move it up and down. Save. Then action, report, save. For some reason, the first time it showed correctly, but upon refresh, the positioning changed. So I had to do it a second time. Very odd.